# Gitlab CI Pipeline - Selenium service cant connect to host

Tags: kotlin, selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci

I've reached WebDriver error `unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` when I want to test my Web application running on job image.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.41)
Build info: version: '4.1.4', revision: '535d840ee2'
System info: host: 'runner-j1aldqxs-project-35693309-concurrent-0', ip: '172.17.0.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.109+', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [0a63e715d2499336585640d785b516c6, get {url=http://runner-j1aldqxs-project-35693309-concurrent-0:8080/}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 101.0.4951.41, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.0mp2co}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:32985}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://172.17.0.3:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 101.0.4951.41, se:vnc: ws://172.17.0.3:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://172.17.0.3:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 0a63e715d2499336585640d785b516c6
```

Has somebody experience like this? Which host should I use within Selenium service to be able to access application running in Gitlab job?

Content of `.gitlab-cy.yml`:

```yaml
image: openjdk:11-jdk

stages:
  - debug

debug:
  stage: debug
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
  before_script:
    - chmod +x ops/waitForHost.sh
  script:
    # hostname for container of current job, it is something like "runner-j1aldqxs-project-35693309-concurrent-0"
    - export APP_TESTS_HOSTNAME="$(hostname)"
    # where selenium service is reachable
    - export APP_TESTS_REMOTE_WEB_DRIVER_URL="http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444"
    # starts web application on image openjdk:11-jdk
    - ./gradlew run --parallel > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    # waiting until application is on and running
    - bash ops/waitForHost.sh localhost:8080 300
    # running tests using webdriver
    - ./gradlew jvmTest --info
```

Simple code snippet of calling running application:

```kotlin
// host, where application is placed
val hostname = System.getenv("APP_TESTS_HOSTNAME")

// this should open homepage in Selenium browser, but error appears
// generated URL is: http://runner-j1aldqxs-project-35693309-concurrent-0:8080/
webDriver.get("http://${hostname}:8080/")
```

Code creating webdriver:

```kotlin
// this works, it connects to Selenium service on http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444
webDriver = RemoteWebDriver(
    URL(System.getenv("APP_TESTS_REMOTE_WEB_DRIVER_URL")),
    ChromeOptions(),
)
```

Has somebody experience like this? Which host should I use within Selenium service to be able to access application running in Gitlab job?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` flag for the job.  Afterwards, the container running the job is accessible under the name “build” from other service containers.  You also might want to consider setting an alias for the Selenium service container.

Something along the lines of this should work:

```yaml
debug:
  stage: debug
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
      alias: chrome
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"
    APP_TESTS_HOSTNAME: "build"
    APP_TESTS_REMOTE_WEB_DRIVER_URL: "http://chrome:4444"
  before_script:
    - chmod +x ops/waitForHost.sh
  script:
    # starts web application on image openjdk:11-jdk
    - ./gradlew run --parallel > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    # waiting until application is on and running
    - bash ops/waitForHost.sh localhost:8080 300
    # running tests using webdriver
    - ./gradlew jvmTest --info
```

---

References:

1. https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#create-a-network-for-each-job

Comment: thx, it helped, I can now use selenium as service, but the last problem is, that selenium can not access application running on localhost through "build" host:



`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [2fc93a524fe1d25aa7d8fdce72f9adc2, get {url=http://build:8080/}]`

Comment: never mind, I have fixed it by running application on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` ip address